# How to aquire thumbnails of MediaStore Album items in API 29+?

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the thumbnail of a media store album item in API 29+. All old methods of doing this(like MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART or MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails) have been deprecated and don't work when using the new scoped storage.

I already tried using the new ContentResolver.loadThumbnail method that is mentioned in all deprecated methods but it always returns null for me.

```
val projection = arrayOf(
    MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID,
)

val cursor = context.contentResolver.query(
    MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    projection,
    null,
    null,
    null
)

cursor?.apply {
    if (moveToFirst()) {
        val albumIdIndex = getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID)

        val albumId = getLong(albumIdIndex)

        val uri = ContentUris.appendId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.buildUpon(), albumId).build()

        // albumArt is always null
        val albumArt = context.contentResolver.loadThumbnail(uri, Size(640, 640), null)
    }

    close()
}
```

The thumbnail is always null but should be a valid bitmap

Comment: @pskink I have tried `MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ID` and it still doesn't work

Comment: @pskink `MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART` is always null when using the new scoped storage. It is also marked as deprecated.

Comment: Do you have proper permission to access it ?

Comment: @PawanKumar Yes, getting album art for individual songs works just fine and seems to be the only workaround so far.

Comment: Did you already found a fix for this?

Comment: @VinceVD No, it seems like you can only get the thumbnails of individual songs and not of albums.

Comment: @Tim one thing i noticed is that in your query you're using the content uri `MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` instead of  `MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`